Enviar variables a un api que esta estructurado con un array dentro de otro array
Es mi primera vez integrando con api, y me ha costado un poco.
El api que recibí tiene un array dentro de otro array
"producto":
[{
    "num":"7702035432506",
    "unidades":1,
    "full":35700,
    "precio":28550
}],
"datos_usuario":
[{
    "cedula":"17350178",
    "tipo":"1",
    "nombres":"JAIRO",
    "apellidos":"LAVERDE POLANIA",
    "email":"gfhfjhj@HOTMAIL.COM",
}]

estoy creando un modulo en php y html para enviar estas variables a la url. Pero no se como hacerlo cuando se tiene un array dentro de otro array.
Agradeciendo su apoyo y muchas gracias

Primero imprime la estructura del array y luego accede a cada propiedad así:
$array = [
    "producto" => [
        "num" => "7702035432506", 
        "unidades" => 1, 
        "full" => 35700, 
        "precio" => 28550
    ], 
    "datos_usuario" => [
        "cedula" => "17350178", 
        "tipo" => "1", 
        "nombres" => "JAIRO", 
        "apellidos" => "LAVERDE POLANIA", 
        "email" => "gfhfjhj@HOTMAIL.COM"
    ]
];

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';

$producto = $array['producto']['num'];
$nombre = $array['datos_usuario']['nombres'];
$apellido = $array['datos_usuario']['apellidos'];

echo 'El Producto <b>'.$producto.'</b> de <b>'.$nombre.' '.$apellido.'</b>';

Resultado de imprimir el array
Array
(
    [producto] => Array
        (
            [num] => 7702035432506
            [unidades] => 1
            [full] => 35700
            [precio] => 28550
        )

    [datos_usuario] => Array
        (
            [cedula] => 17350178
            [tipo] => 1
            [nombres] => JAIRO
            [apellidos] => LAVERDE POLANIA
            [email] => gfhfjhj@HOTMAIL.COM
        )

)

Resultado en pantalla del echo PHP
El Producto 7702035432506 de JAIRO LAVERDE POLANIA
Bajo esa misma premisa envías las variables que quieras por url, eso si, cuidado con lo que mandes por GET. Si necesitas enviar algo crítico, usa POST.

Lee esta pregunta reciente por favor y aprende un poco más de los arrays 
